# Save to .settings file diffrence between 2 diffrent ways of saving

Tags: winforms, settings, msdn

I was reading about the `.settings` file on msdn and I noticed they give 2 examples of how to set the value of a item in the settings. Now my question is what is the real diffrence between the 2 and when would you use one instead of the other, since to me they seem pretty mutch the same.

> To Write and Persist User Settings at Run Time
>   Access the user setting and assign it a new value, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
> ```
>
> If you want to persist changes to user settings between application sessions, call the Save method, as shown in the following code:
>
> ```
> Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
> ```

Comment: First is setting blue color in your application. Second is saving this color so you could reuse it in the next launch of the application.

Comment: So if i understand it correctly the first one would set it so you can use it as long as the application doesn't get closed. and if you use the second one you actualy save it even if you restart the application.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Why don't you try yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement updates the value of the setting in memory.  The second statement updates the persisted value in the user.config file on the disk.  That second statement is required to get the value back when you restart the program.

It is very, very important to realize that these two statements *must* be separate and never be written close together in your code.  Keeping them close is *harakiri-code*.  Settings tend to implement unsubtle features in your code, making it operate differently.  Which isn't always perfectly tested.  What you strongly want to avoid is persisting a setting value that subsequently crashes your program.

That's the harakiri angle, if you saved that value then it is highly likely that the program will immediately crash again when the user restarts it.  Or in other words, your program will never run correctly again.

The Save() call must be made when you have a reasonable guarantee that nothing bad happened when the new setting value was used.  It belongs at the end of your Main() method.  Only reached when the program terminated normally.